# blueimp jQuery-File-Upload library convert GIF image to PNG after resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, blueimp

I have set options provided by library like below:

```
    disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
        .test(window.navigator && navigator.userAgent),
    imageMaxWidth: 1440,
    imageMaxHeight: 1080,
    imageQuality: 0.95,
    imageCrop: false, // Force cropped images
    maxFileSize: 10000000,
    disableExifThumbnail: true,
    disableExifSub: true,
    disableExifGps: true,
    disableImagePreview: true,
```

Can anyone help to resolve this issue?

I want to retain the original image type as it is like if it's a GIF image it should be uploaded as GIF not PNG after resizing.

Comment: If you figured anything out, please update here. I am having exact same problem.

Comment: I spent hours thinking that why validations are not working for me, and then I figured THIS out. I really don't want to mess around editing the library.

Answer (score 0):

Set `disableImageResize = true;`
When it's false the plugin read locally the image and create and image/png blob... that is sent to the HTTP request

Comment: But this will stop client side image resizing, no ?
I need client side image resizing too.

Comment: Oh yeah :/ In my case I don't need the image resizing

Comment: Resizing image, the image is loaded as base64 URL. An PNG image base64 URL. Maybe you can resize the image in backend...